# capture special characters ! in echo command for zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I am trying to capture a string in mac terminal zsh

when i try

```
echo "abc1234!"
```

It would prompt for dquote>

I have tried adding a additional quote like this

```
echo "abc1234!""
```

Output

```
abc1234
```

how do i capture ! character in the string ??

Answer (score 0):

Either turn off history expansion with

```
setopt nobanghist
```

, or escape the `!`character:

```
echo "abc1234\!"
```